# Bash - listing files neatly

Tags: bash

I have a non-determinate list of file names that I would like to output to the user in a script. I don't mind if it's a paragraph or in columns (like the out put of `ls`. How does `ls` manage it?). In fact I only have the following requirements:

1. file names need to stay on the same line (yes, that even means files with a space in their name. If someone is dumb enough to use a newline in a filename, though, they deserve what they get.)
2. If the output is formatted as a paragraph, I'd like to see it indented on the left and right to separate it from other text. Sort of like the way `apt-get upgrade` handles the list of packages to install.
3. I would love not to write my own function for this - at least not a complicated one. There are so many text formatting utilities in linux!
4. The utility should be available in the default Ubuntu install.
5. It should handle relatively large input, just in case. Something like 2000 characters or so?

It seems like a simple proposition, but I can't seem to get it to work. The `column` command is out simply because it can't handle large chunks of data. `fmt` and `fold` both don't care about delimiters. `printf` looks like it would work... if I wrote a script for it.

Is there a more flexible tool I've overlooked, or a simple way to do this?

Comment: What, like `ls -1` (that's the number 1)?

Comment: No, just `ls` (with it's varied columns). Unfortunately I can't use `ls` directly, since the files are not all in the same directory.

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately the only thing I could suggest is `printf`. Maybe someone else will come along with something better.

Comment: Do you want just the file names, or some component of their path too? If you just want names without directories, you could do an ugly hack: create a directory somewhere (`/dev/shm` might be a good choice). Loop through each file name and create it in your directory with `touch`. `cd` to your directory, run `ls`, and then delete the directory.

Comment: Find out how `ls` does it in [the source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/ls.c;h=8b5b2cf74aae962320b21f7d3d8a73208beb2778;hb=HEAD)

Comment: @yellowantphil Just the filenames. Nice ugly hack! Way to think outside the box. Not exactly what I'm looking for, though.

Comment: @glenn Thanks for digging up the source! Alas, it's 5000 lines long and written in C.

Comment: If the only thing missing from the default `ls` formatting is the spacing on the left, then maybe you could run `COLUMNS=$(($COLUMNS-10))` to narrow the output, and then prepend spaces using `printf` or some other tool. Edit: now that I try it, `ls` seems to ignore $COLUMNS anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to run `ls` on filenames stored in a variable (that contain spaces?) I noticed you can `ls "foo bar" more` and that works, but I can't figure out how to make it work if the filenames are in a variable.

Comment: If you fill `$files` with file names separated by newlines, then set `IFS=$'\n'`, then `ls -d $files` should work.

Comment: @JoBu1324 If your filenames are in a variable you can use echo to pr **`echo "$var" | pr -3 -t`**

Comment: Below I have a solution that (1) doesn't split "file name" across two lines, (2) formats the output as a paragraph, with an indent, just like `apt-get upgrade` (3) it's not a complicated function, OTOH the many formatting utilities available all have the defect of thinking that a space is a space is a space, and hence no one satisfies your first point, (4) is `awk` available in a default Ubuntu install? I don't know, possibly yes but I don't know (5) no problems with large inputs, say 20000 characters or so (the only problem being to read all the output...). Ciao from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have a simple formatter that, it seems to me, is good enough

```
% ls | awk '
      NR==1 {for(i=1;i<9;i++)printf "----+----%d", i; print ""
             line="  " $0;l=2+length($0);next}
            {if(l+1+length($0)>80){
                print line; line = "  " $0 ; l = 2+length($0) ; next}
            {l=l+length($0)+1; line=line " " $0}}'
----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8
  3inarow.py 5s.py a.csv a.not1.pdf a.pdf as de.1 asde.1 asdef.txt asde.py a.sh
  a.tex auto a.wk bizarre.py board.py cc2012xyz2_5_5dp.csv cc2012xyz2_5_5dp.html
  cc.py col.pdf col.sh col.sh~ col.tex com.py data data.a datazip datidisk
  datizip.py dd.py doc1.pdf doc1.tex doc2 doc2.pdf doc2.tex doc3.pdf doc3.tex
  e.awk Exit file file1 file2 geomedian.py group_by_1st group_by_1st.2
  group_by_1st.mawk integers its.py join.py light.py listluatexfonts mask.py
  mat.rix my_data nostop.py numerize.py pepp.py pepp.pyc pi.pdf pippo muore
  pippo.py pi.py pi.tex pizza.py plocol.py points.csv points.py puddu puffo
%
```

I had to simulate input using `ls` because you didn't care to show how to access your list of files. The window width is arbitrary as well, but it's easy to provide a value to a `-V width=...` option of `awk`

#### *Edit*

I added a header line, an unrequested header line, to my `awk` script because I wanted to test the effectiveness of the (very simple) algorithm.

#### *Addendum*

I'd like to stress that the simple formatter above ***doesn't split "file names" like this across lines***, as in the following example:

```
% ls -d1 b*
bia nconodi
bianconodi.pdf
bianconodi.ppt
bin
b.txt
% ls | awk '
      NR==1 {for(i=1;i<9;i++)printf "----+----%d", i; print ""
             line="  " $0;l=2+length($0);next}
            {if(l+1+length($0)>80){
                print line; line = "  " $0 ; l = 2+length($0) ; next}
            {l=l+length($0)+1; line=line " " $0}}'
----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8
  04_Tower.pdf 2plots.py 2.txt a.csv aiuole asdefff a.txt a.txt~ auto 
  bia nconodi bianconodi.pdf bianconodi.ppt bin Borsa Ferna.jpg b.txt
  ...
%
```

As you can see, in the first line there is enough space to print `bia` but not enough for the real filename `bia nconodi`, that hence is printed on the second line.

#### *Addendum 2*

This is the formatter the OP eventually went with:

```
local margin=4
local max=10
echo -e "$filenames" | awk -v width=$(tput cols) -v margin=$margin '
    NR==1 {
        for (i=0; i<margin; i++) {
            line = line " " 
        }
        line = line $0; 
        l = margin + margin + length($0);
        next;
    }
    {
        if (l+1+length($0) > width) {
            print line;
            line = ""
            for (i=0; i<margin; i++) line=line " " 
            line = line $0 ;
            l = margin + margin + length($0) ;
            next;
        }
        {
            l = l + length($0) + 1;
            line = line "  " $0; 
        }   
    }
    END {
        print line;
    }'
```

Comment: This does come the closest to fulfilling my requirements, although it is a script. Mind if I update your answer with the awk script I ended up with?

Comment: @JoBu1324 It has to be a script, standard formatters trust white space in their input... About updating, my answer is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your filenames in a variable this will create 3 columns, you can change -3 to whatever number of columns you want

```
echo "$var" | pr -3 -t
```

or if you need to get them from the filesystem:

```
find . -printf "%f\n" 2>/dev/null | pr -3 -t
```

From what you stated in the comments, I think this may be what you are looking for. The find command prints the file or directory name along with a newline and you can put additional filtering of the filenames by piping through `grep` or `sed` prior to `pr` - the `pr` command is for print and the `-3` states `3` columns and `-t` is for omit headers and trailers - you can adjust it to your preferences.

Comment: I only want to display a subset ("non-determinant") of files. Find doesn't fit.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-determinant"? Can you give an example?

Comment: It's a random list of files &/or folders that the user is in control of. The files must have a specific extension to be discoverable, but the folders can be anything.

Comment: Do you want to print only the contents of the file? Or you need to take the file contents and verify that they are on the system?

Comment: @JoBu1324, `find` can absolutely print files with a specific extension, or directories with any extension. `find . -type d -o '(' -type f -a -name '*.foo' ')'`

Comment: @JoBu1324, ...`find` can even run an arbitrary program you give it to decide whether a given file/directory should be included in its output. Don't underestimate `find`; it's a _very_ powerful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for `/usr/bin/fold`?

```
printf '%s ' * | fold -w 77 | sed -e 's/^/   /'
```

Replace the `*` with your list, of course; if your files are in an array (they should be; storing filenames in scalar variables is lossy), that'd be `"${your_array[@]}"`.